# How come the pandas have this OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp error?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have seen several solutions for this 'OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp' error for some extreme dates in pandas but none of them really address a solution. How come a widespread data analytics library like Pandas released this limitation?

Other than substituting NaT value, Is there any proper wrap-around against this limitation by keeping these days in datetime format??

Comment: do you have a specific application where this is a problem?

Comment: Yeah, I often deal with historical data and need to convert the dates in the format of seconds precisely.  pd.to_datetime do help a lot when I deal with normal dates in my workflow.

Comment: So, could you please provide a specific example? Since pandas is using nanosecond precision Unix time as internal datetime representation, it's limited to what a 64 bit integer can hold. You cannot have both the precision and an unlimited range with that kind of data structure. Vanilla Python has reduced precision (microseconds), thus a larger range. If pandas had chosen that precision, likely, other people would have complained, about insufficient precision ;-)

Comment: eg: For the earthquake data, there will be historical earthquakes, or at least the earthquakes that occurred before 1960s, and it is necessary to calculate the time difference between the events (precision up to milli seconds would be enough).

Also, I am looking for a perfect format to represent this kind of data, Decimal year seems to be not so uniform, due to unequal days.

Comment: Can't you just use int or float for seconds since the epoch? Then you can easily calculate differences. If at any moment you need the actual date, you can always generate python datetime: `df.time_column.apply(datetime.fromtimestamp)` BTW, pandas timestamp min is 1677-09-21 00:12:43.145224193